# Sporadic "Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided." errors running build pipeline on Azure DevOps

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops

We have a suite of E2E tests we are running on a build pipeline on Azure DevOps.

When the pipeline starts, the solution is built and an Azure resource group is created.

Each test creates its own VM under the resource group and each VM is created from an image hosted on Azure, with up to 5 VMs created for each pipeline run.

Each VM has its own instance of SQL Server installed and we are waiting for service to start before making any database calls.

When each test completes, it releases the VM it ran on back into a queue / pool for the next test to use.

However, sometimes (around 1 out of every 25 tests), when the next test starts, it errors at the first database call, stating SQL Server login failed for 'sa' user because of incorrect password.

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8. 2024-02-02 15:55:19.01 Logon Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided.

Which is interesting, because the previous test was able to connect to SQL Server just fine with the same connection string.

For the time being, we've added a rerun / retry test step in the pipeline to catch any sporadic environmental failures like this SQL login error, but would like to find the root cause of why this error is happening sometimes.

Have also tried restarting MSSQLSERVER service and retrying SQL Server connection but the same error gets thrown, and eventually a state 78 error for user is locked out

Any ideas as to what could be causing the issue or what I should look into to help diagnose the issue?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question and got some reasonable answers?

Comment: 1. Are you using a self-hosted agent or a MS-hosted agent? 2. Have you configured any firewall? 3. Have you tried running your test outside the DevOps pipeline, such as locally, will the same issue occur? If it's convenient, you can try it to narrow down this problem. If the same issue occurs locally, we can know that it isn't related to the pipeline. 4. When this issue occurred, did you log in to the target VM and see if you could log in to the server using `sa`?

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT
1. This is a self-hosted agent
2. Application server and SQL Server are on the same VM so firewall shouldn't be an issue
3. The issue never occurs running locally
4. Unfortunately I don't have access to go into the VM directly to verify a manual sa login

Is it possible that SQL Server is starting in single user mode, then SQLSERVERAGENT starts an administrative job which takes up the connection slot from sa user?

Comment: "Is it possible that SQL Server is starting in single user mode..." - I am not sure about this. Are you using pipeline tasks to create resource groups and VMs or use your own projects or something else? You can try adding some scripts to delay the pipeline/process after creating the VM but before accessing the SQL server. Then monitor if it has the same issue or not.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT There is a pipeline task to create the resource group at the start of pipeline run, and the VMs themselves are created in each test's setup hook under that rg, with a limit of up to 5 VMs created for 5 tests running in parallel. When each test is done, it releases the VM it was running on back into a pool of available VMs for the next test to connect to. We do have a delay of 180 seconds when the VM is first created to wait for SQL Server to start up and be connectable, the thing is, the error NEVER occurs when a VM is first created -- it only shows up on subsequent tests

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT And adding the artificial delay to the tests that ran on available VMs didn't seem to resolve the issue, once the next test uses the same VM, MSSQLSERVER service is already Running on that VM, most tests are able to connect and run the first db query ok, but it's about 1 out of 30 tests that error at SQL Server sa login for incorrect password